# How to redirect to a component if user accessing a protected route, directly through browser url?

Tags: angular

I have successfully made a login page in angular 7 using protected routes and now if the user tries login with correct credentials it will redirect to a Dashboard component and if credentials are false it will just display a message "Invalid login" in login component itself.

Now how can I configure if the user is directly browsing to the protected component through browser URL? 
currently, it's displaying just blank page and not getting accesses to the protected route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first subscribe to the Router events.
Write

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
     console.log(val);
    });
}
```

in the constructor of your app component.
This will detect all URL changes and also direct route change . In the subscribe method, write your logic

Comment: Thanks, bro

That works fine
Also referred to https://medium.com/@nsrathore/router-event-handling-angular-5-5-2-0-723bfe39cdf1

Comment: I have done that as u said but getting another error now.
now if I am accessing the protected route through browser URL am redirecting to login component and its working fine.

but getting an error in console "Cannot activate an already activated outlet".

also after this error login not working.

Comment: I think you have a CanActivate service which you have added in the route, Kindly check it .
also are u using `window.location.href=url or this.router.navigateByUrl(url)`

Comment: yes, am using canActivate for dashboard component in routermodule

also using router.navigate([' ']); for navigation

Comment: ok i think you are already in the dashboard component and again trying to redirect to the same .

Comment: No,

my home is my login component and there i browsed to /dashboard through url and it redirected to login again..
but that error occurs "Cannot activate an already activated outlet"

Comment: Problem solved.
Initially, I have used NavigationCancel instance toTrue, but now using GuardsCheckEnd instance.Shouldactivate ==false and then redirecting to login page

Answer (score 1):

you must use Authguard to protect your routes.

in the router module file, you must have something like this:

```
canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
```

and in AuthGuard file you should check the token, if the user has a valid token then he/she can get to that route if not, you can redirect it to the login page.

AuthGuard file should be like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivateChild, RouterStateSnapshot} from 
'@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import {LocalDataService} from '../services/local-data.service';
import {SessionStorage} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {

@SessionStorage('token')
public token;


canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
if(this.token){
return true;
}
this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
return false;

}
}
```